FRM-41214 Unable to Run Report ,FRM-41217 unable to get job report status
Find any Bug , Help me Out
PROCEDURE PRINT_1 IS
    repid           REPORT_OBJECT; 
    v_rep           varchar2(512); 
    rep_status      varchar2(512); 
    pl_id ParamList;
Begin
    pl_id := Get_Parameter_List('tmpdata');
    IF NOT Id_Null(pl_id) THEN
    Destroy_Parameter_List( pl_id );
    END IF;
    pl_id := Create_Parameter_List('tmpdata');
    add_parameter(pl_id,'P_1',text_parameter, :CUSTOMER.ORDER_ID);
    add_parameter(pl_id,'PARAMFORM',text_parameter, 'NO');
    
        repid := find_report_object('INV_PRINT');
            SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(repid, REPORT_EXECUTION_MODE, RUNTIME);
            SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(repid, REPORT_SERVER, 'rep_wls_reports_server'); 
            SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(repid, REPORT_COMM_MODE, SYNCHRONOUS);   
            SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(repid, REPORT_DESTYPE, CACHE);
                SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(repid, REPORT_DESFORMAT, 'PDF');         
        v_rep:= RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(repid,pl_id); 
        rep_status:= report_object_status(v_rep); 
  WHILE rep_status in ('RUNNING','OPENING_REPORT','ENQUEUED') 
  LOOP 
    rep_status := report_object_status(v_rep); 
  END LOOP; 

    IF rep_status = 'FINISHED' THEN 
        message('Report Completed Succesfully');    
     WEB.SHOW_DOCUMENT('http://SERVER:9002/reports/rwservlet/getjobid'||substr(v_rep,instr(v_rep,'_',-1)+1) ||'?'||'server=rep_wls_reports_server','_blank');
    ELSE
      message(rep_status); 
      
    END IF; 
    
END;
Comments

Call Oracle Report from Oracle forms passing single Parameter.
under the Button Pressed , calling Report gives me Error
FRM-41214 Unable to Run Report ,FRM-41217 unable to get job report status and
REP-52251: The output of job ID 0 requested on Thu Aug 15 15:22:33 PKT 2024 cannot be retrieved.REP-56033: Job 0 does not exist.
